# How to debug NSAPI plugins in Xcode

Tags: xcode, nsapi

How does one debug NSAPI plugins in Xcode?

The Apple developer documentation for NSAPI based WebKit plugins for Safari states that these can be debugged in Xcode.  The only documentation I could find for this was out of date:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1500/_index.html

Although I was able to configure Xcode 4.5 to build an NSAPI plugin, launch Safari (with a test page that will load the plugin), and copy a symlink to the debug build into Library/Internet Plug-Ins, I cannot actually debug the plugin.  The debugger is associated with the Safari process and not the plugin.